# Version incompatibility in SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I've created `SSIS package,` and now I want to create `SQL Agent Job`. But when I create and run it, I receive the following error:

[image]

Which states about version incompatibility. I'm using `SQL Sver 2008R2`. How can I change its version so that it will be compatible with minimum effort? Interesting, but when I run package in `Visual Studio`, it runs perfectly.

I've tried to download `BIDS` for `2008R2,` but it doesn't open my project made in another version, and I don't want to create it from scratch.

Comment: You can't change the version number because the package format is fundamentally different. When they built SSIS 2008 they had no idea what format SSIS 2012 or 2014 would be. Why are you trying to run a 2012/2014 package in SQL 2008? Either upgrade your SQL Server to 2012 / 2014 or redevelop in BIDS

Comment: Basically if you have no good reason to be running SQL Server 2008 then upgrade to SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to achive this (see [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42641/convert-sql-server-2012-ssis-package-to-2008)).
But you can:

- Take 2 machines,
- One with 2008 and the other with 2012/2014,
- Bring up the 2012/2014 solution in one and start a new 2008 solution in the other,
- Use the 2012/2014 version as a script and replicate it in the 2008 system.

You must setup it separatly on 2 machines because SSIS version can overwrite one another during installation and also it can be difficult to get both running on the same machine.
Once we have the same issue and that recommendation (found it somewhere on the internet) was our only way to downgrade to 2008.